# Android - Get webpage content into a String

Tags: java, android, crash, runtime-error

I am developing a new application, and it needs to get a JSON object from my website in the url [http://10.0.0.8/mybiren/json.php](http://belenky.ddns.net/mybiren/json.php) (I'm aware that it's a local ip, it's just for testing the app).
I've got the function that gets the content of the site, and it have worked on a regular Java project, but when I tried it on my Android aplication project it have failed. when I've debugged the app in order to find where it stops, it have stopped on the line that calls `yc.getInputStream()` (yc is a URLConnection object). My friend said that I must add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to my AndroidManifest.xml but it didn't help. 
Stack Trace doesn't show anything special

---

### Java code

```
package com.example.arghh_mybiren;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void getJson(View v)
    {
        URL u;
        try {
            u = new URL("http://10.0.0.8/mybiren/json.php");

        URLConnection yc = u.openConnection();
        yc.setDoInput(true);
        yc.setDoOutput(true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream())); //debugger crashed here
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.arghh_mybiren.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="getJson"
        android:onClick="getJson" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### Stack Trace

```
11-04 19:59:26.452: I/PGA(17170): New SOCKET connection: com.example.mybiren (pid 17170, tid 17170)
11-04 19:59:26.452: W/PGA(17170): [17170] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x5579a7a0, 0x0, 0x787ae3b8, 0x775840e0)
11-04 19:59:26.462: W/PGA(17170): [17170] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x5579a7a0, 0x0, 0x787ae3b8, 0x775840e0) returned
11-04 19:59:26.472: D/OpenGLRenderer(17170): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really dont know what was wrong, but my friend sucseeded in helping me and sent me the following code (that have worked to me):

### Java code

```
package com.example.arghh_mybiren;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String ... urls) 
        {
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
                //String j = (String) uc.getContent();
                uc.setDoInput(true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    a.append(inputLine);
                in.close();

                return a.toString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button loadBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_load);
        loadBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Load();

            }
        });
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MyTask taskLoad = new MyTask();
        taskLoad.execute("http://10.0.0.8/mybiren/JSON.php?day=Monday");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

### XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.arghh_mybiren.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_load"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="getJson"
        android:onClick="getJson" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

thanks to all who tried to help me.